# Amazon instant video tries using flash instead of Silverlight/Pipelight

Tags: firefox, xubuntu

I try using Amazon Instant Video on Xubuntu 15.04 with Firefox and Pipelight. I had it working before (Ubuntu 14.10) but did a fresh install for other reasons.

Pipelight seems to be installed fine, I also added HAL, but still, Amazon Instant Video tries to use Flash (which fails, since I removed Flash). I also told Amazon to use Silverlight instead of Flash, but still no success.

The Pipelight test page tells me my Silverlight plugin is working, I am just not showing a Windows user agent. I do not remember fiddling with my user agent settings, so I am a bit lost here.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I can just use google chrome - it plays amazon intant video fine. Note that google-chromium, the open source upstream project does not do the trick, you need the google version.